# How do I write a "filter" generator in python?

Tags: python, filter, generator

I'm studying the topic of generators in python and I can't solve an exercise.

I have to write a "filter" generator that takes a predicate and a sequence and produces a sequence that has no elements for which the predicate is true. (similar to the built-in filter function)

I know how to solve an exercise through a function, but I do not know how to solve it through "yield".

This is my code:

```
def filter(x, lst):
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        if lst[i] != x:
            yield lst[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            continue
```

I'd be glad to get help with the task.

Comment: it would be more pythonic to do `for item in lst` than while loop. `else` is completely unnecessary, but you can leave it for stylistic purposes.

Comment: Wait, you already use yield.. so what is it that you are asking exactly? (also, I second the suggestion that you use a for loop. Whenever you have an iterable, don't use a while-loop to iterate over it, *that's what for-loops are for* and its much cleaner)

Comment: I show you what I wrote, but my code doesn't work. It's going into recursion. And I don't understand the difference between yield and return

Answer (score 2):

you may use:

```
def my_filter(pred, seq):
    for item in seq:
        if not pred(item):
            yield item
```

`my_filter` generator is iterating over your sequence and when an element applied over the predicate it is `False` then will yield that element

example:

```
list(my_filter(lambda x: x >4, [0, 1, 5, 2]))

# [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator literal to accomplish this in one line

```py
def my_filter(x, lst):
    yield from (i for i in lst if i != x)
```

This uses the return keyword instead of yield, but is actually equivalent as it also returns a generator which yields the same items.

```py
def my_filter(x, lst):
    return (i for i in lst if i != x)
```

Comment: the yield from version seems really overwrought. Note, this doesn't actually satisfy the OPs requirements.